# Code stops running after class' constructor

Tags: javascript

When I declare a constructor method in a class that extends another class, nothing works after an object is created from the class. Why is it like this?

```js
class test{
  
}

class test2 extends test {
  constructor(){ //this makes the alert(2); not working
  
  }
}

alert(1); //this works
var e = new test2(); //nothing after this works
alert(2); //this doesn't run
```

Comment: It also shows a huge self-explaining error in the console.

Comment: Did you read the error message in your console? You can see it when you run the code snippet. You can also see it if you open your developer tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call super() in your contructor:

```
class test2 extends test {
  constructor(){ //this makes the alert(2); not working
    super(); 
  }
}
```